Angular highchart Bar chart disable hover
I am using angular highcharts and I want to be able to select single stacked bar chart.
I want to be able to select single stacked bar or disable hover.
I am not sure if this was possible, but I found custom code which individually selects bars for each category. But I want to remove hover effects of the chart since hover effects are shared for each series.
https://jsfiddle.net/wvnpd4ze/
I am not able to remove the hover for it.
data = [{
    hName: "hh1",
    eaCount: 5,
    neaCount: 12,
    peaCount: 6,
    allAccCount: 23
},

{
    hName: "hh2",
    eaCount: 6,
    neaCount: 6,
    peaCount: 4,
    allAccCount: 14
},

{
    hName: "hh3",
    eaCount: 15,
    neaCount: 9,
    peaCount: 6,
    allAccCount: 30
},
{
    hName: "hh4",
    eaCount: 20,
    neaCount: 12,
    peaCount: 8,
    allAccCount: 40
},
{
    hName: "hh5",
    eaCount: 25,
    neaCount: 15,
    peaCount: 10,
    allAccCount: 50
},
{
    hName: "hh6",
    eaCount: 30,
    neaCount: 18,
    peaCount: 12,
    allAccCount: 60
},
{
    hName: "hh7",
    eaCount: 35,
    neaCount: 21,
    peaCount: 14,
    allAccCount: 70
},
{
    hName: "hh8",
    eaCount: 40,
    neaCount: 24,
    peaCount: 16,
    allAccCount: 80
},
{
    hName: "hh9",
    eaCount: 45,
    neaCount: 27,
    peaCount: 18,
    allAccCount: 90
},
{
    hName: "hh10",
    eaCount: 50,
    neaCount: 30,
    peaCount: 20,
    allAccCount: 100
},
{
    hName: "hh11",
    eaCount: 55,
    neaCount: 33,
    peaCount: 22,
    allAccCount: 110
},
{
    hName: "hh12",
    eaCount: 60,
    neaCount: 36,
    peaCount: 24,
    allAccCount: 120
},
{
    hName: "hh13",
    eaCount: 65,
    neaCount: 39,
    peaCount: 26,
    allAccCount: 130
},
{
    hName: "hh14",
    eaCount: 70,
    neaCount: 42,
    peaCount: 28,
    allAccCount: 140
},
{
    hName: "hh15",
    eaCount: 75,
    neaCount: 45,
    peaCount: 30,
    allAccCount: 150
},
{
    hName: "hh16",
    eaCount: 80,
    neaCount: 48,
    peaCount: 32,
    allAccCount: 160
},
{
    hName: "hh17",
    eaCount: 85,
    neaCount: 51,
    peaCount: 34,
    allAccCount: 170
},
{
    hName: "hh18",
    eaCount: 90,
    neaCount: 54,
    peaCount: 36,
    allAccCount: 180 

},
{
    hName: "hh19",
    eaCount: 95,
    neaCount: 57,
    peaCount: 38,
    allAccCount: 190
},
{
    hName: "hh20",
    eaCount: 100,
    neaCount: 60,
    peaCount: 40,
    allAccCount: 200
}

];

Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
            type: 'bar',
            scrollablePlotArea: {
                minHeight: 800,
                opacity: 0.97
            },
            marginRight: 25
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: data.map(detail => detail.hName),
            title: {
                text: 'hh'
            }
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            tickInterval: 50,
            title: {
                text: 'Number of Acc',
            },
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled: false,
                    halo: {
                        size: 0
                    }
                }
            },
            series: {
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: false,
                        halo: {
                            size: 0
                        }
                    }
                },
                stacking: 'normal',
                pointPadding: 0,
                groupPadding: 0.2,
                pointWidth: 30,
                padding: 5,
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function () {
                            var clickedPoint = this,
                                chart = clickedPoint.series.chart;
                            chart.series.forEach(function (s) {
                                s.points.forEach(function (p) {
                                    if (p.x == clickedPoint.x) {
                                        p.select(null, true);
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    states: {
                        select: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
                },

            },
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                states: {
                        select: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
            },

        },
        series: [
            {
                name: 'Partial',
                data: data.map(detail => detail.peaCount),
                color: '#523594',
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'Not',
                data: data.map(detail => detail.neaCount),
                color: '#A11D2A',
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'En',
                data: data.map(detail => detail.eaCount),
                color: '#869338',
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            },
        ]
});

I tried disabling hover in multiple places, but its still showing.

To disable hover you need to set states.hover.enabled option to false and set states.inactive.opacity option to 1, demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ucg23v08/

"To select single stacked bar" do you mean that clicking bar placed on the x equal to 0 should highlight all the bars placed on x equal to 0?

@DominikChudy inactive solved the hover issue. Thanks!

That's great to hear! Then I'll add it as an official answer to your question.

To disable hover you need to set states.hover.enabled option to false and set states.inactive.opacity option to 1.
API references:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.states.hover.enabled
Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ucg23v08/
plotOptions: {
series: {
  stacking: 'normal',
  states: {
    hover: {
      enabled: false
    },
    inactive: {
      opacity: 1
    }
  }
}

},
